# exporting classes to DLLs

Tags: c++, dll

hello im a bit confused with DLLs right now so i came here to ask where there are alot of pros in programming
so ive got this class called GUI.h and the GUI.cpp

```
class GUI
{
    public:
        GUI(void);
        virtual ~GUI();
        void Draw(float x,float y,float z);
        void Texture(int num);
        bool Shutdown();
        void TextureON(int num);
        void TextureOFF(int num);

    private:
    GUIWeapon * Weapon;
    GUIWeaponA * Weapona;
    GUIArrow * Arrow;
    GUIHP * hp;
    GUIStop * stop;
    GUISpeed * Speed;
    float XCam,YCam,ZCam;
    bool DrawStop;

};
```

so how am i suppossed to export this to a DLL i have made DLLs but not with classes so how am im suppossed to declare the Constructor,Destructor and call the other GUIFunctions in other headers?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I would rather provide a C interface instead. Much easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify a compiler or operating system, but if this is Windows and Microsoft C++, then you can use __declspec(dllexport) on a class to export it from a DLL. You then use __declspec(dllimport) on the same class when you include the header to be consumed elsewhere.

However, I tend to recommend against exporting classes from DLLs. It's an ok plan if all the DLLs always ship together and are built together. [Where the DLL is just used to delay loading of code]. If you are using DLLs to provide actual components that ship separately, you should use an actual versionable abstraction like COM.

Martyn

Comment: okay thank you very much im also against it but it was really a homework im not doing now lol

Comment: @Makenshi: then use the homework tag next time

Answer (score 1):

Export like this:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) GUI 
{...}
```

Import like this:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) GUI 
{...}
```

Or simply define a macro like this:

```
#if _DEFINE_THIS_IN_YOUR_DLL_
    #define CLASS_IMPORT_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define CLASS_IMPORT_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

And directly use it:

```
class CLASS_IMPORT_EXPORT GUI
{
};
```

Be sure to have SINGLE header file for both DLL and its clients.

But it important to note that you `sizeof` class in DLL and the client (EXE) must be same. It may happen, for example, that you have an array of SOME_SIZE which is defined as macro. In DLL, it might be `100` but in EXE it might be `200` (for whatsoever reason). This would just break the class, when you call some function the `this` pointer would be correct; but not the class (that means `sizeof(GUI-in-DLL) != sizeof(GUI-in-EXE)`.

Exporting a class also means exposing all of the data members included it it. This would mean exposing all other classes/structures/typedef/private variables and so on. For the solution, one might calculate the size of all data-members (say 154 bytes), and declare a `char filler[154]` in class declration (for hiding actual data).
While this would practically work, compiler linker, debugger etc would not have any issues - but not flexible for programmer.

Irrespective if you hide the actual data declaration with filler-bytes or not, you must also ensure #pragma packing. For one, if DLL is having 4 bytes packing, and EXE is having (even by mistake) 1 byte packing, you are in total mess. And this mistake/bug is hard to detect!

The best solution, IMO, is to export a class having a pointer to class that implements the actual functionality. This means `GUI_Internal`/`GUI_Core` and exporting just `GUI` having pointer of either of these classes:

```
class IMPORT_EXPORT GUI
{
   GUI_Internal* pInternal; // 4/8 bytes only! EXACT
   // ... Export functions
};
```

But this would require the client-of-DLL (at compiler level) to know what `GUI_Internal` is. For this, just have a `typedef`:

```
#if _DEFINE_THIS_IN_YOUR_DLL_
typedef GUI_Internal* ClassPointer;
#else
typedef void* ClassPointer
#endif
```

and use it:

```
class CLASS_IMPORT_EXPORT GUI 
{ 
ClassPointer pointer; // Name is something else! ... 
};
```

This obviously requires you to allocate pointer with instance of GUI_Internal, and forward functions to that class.