# How to export a C++ class from a dll?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I have a class which has two overloaded functions. How do I export it from a dll and also how to use it by other C++ classes?  My class looks like this:

```
#define DECLDIREXP __declspec(dllexport) 

#define DECLDIRIMP __declspec(dllimport)


class DECLDIREXP xyz 

{

public: 
          void printing();
          void printing(int a);
};  

using namespace std; 

void xyz::printing()
{
        cout<<"hello i donot take any argument";
}


void xyz::printing(int a)
{
        cout<<"hello i take "<< a <<"as argument";
}
```

Comment: To my surprise, I didn't find an existing question which this one duplicates. I would have thought that it's a rather common question.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620791/exporting-classes-to-dlls

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A common approach is to have a single macro (let's call it `EXPORT`) which either expands to `dllimport` or `dllexport` depending on whether some sort of "building the DLL right now" define is set, like this:

```
#ifdef MAKEDLL
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class EXPORT xyz {
  // ...
};
```

The idea is that when building your DLL, you add `MAKEDLL` to the preprocessor definitions. That way, all the code will be exported. Clients who link against your DLL (and hence include this header file) don't need to do anything at all. By not defining `MAKEDLL`, they will automatically import all the code.

The advantage of this approach is that the burden of getting the macros right is moved from the many (the clients) to just the author of the DLL.

The disadvantage of this is that when using the code above as it is, it's no longer possible to just compile the code directly into some client module since it's not possible to define the `EXPORT` macro to nothing. To achieve that, you'd need to have another check which, if true, defines EXPORT to nothing.

On a slightly different topic: in many cases, it's not possible (or desired!) to export a complete class like that. Instead, you may want to just export the symbols you need. For instance, in your case, you may want to just export the two public methods. That way, all the private/protected members won't be exported:

```
class xyz
{
public: 
    EXPORT void printing();
    EXPORT void printing(int a);
};
```

Comment: just remember that Mehrdads answer is correct in the respect that exported classes work only for this specific compiler version & compiler settings. Even mixing Debug & Release is not permitted (e.g. Debug client using Release dll).

Answer (score 14):

As I remember, normally, you export not a class but a factory function that creates a new instance of class and returns a pointer. The class declaration resides in header file for compile time.

I may be wrong about the example (that was long ago), but here how it should approximately look like:

Header file (.h):

```
class MyClass { ... };

extern "C" DLL_API MyClass* createMyClass();
```

Source file (.cpp):

```
DLL_API MyClass* createMyClass() {
    return new MyClass();
}
```

Define MY_DLL_EXPORT while compiling, see foraidt's answer example.

Comment: That's the easiest way to implement it. But don't forget to put factory functions in an extern "C"{} statement. C++'s name mangling may prevent you from loading the function from the dll.

Comment: can you suggest me an example

Answer (score 8):

**One another option:**

Use the **default** defined macro **local** to the project.

You can see the default defined macros local to the project in the below location:

**Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definition.**

**Example:**

Suppose your Project Name is: **MyDLL**

Default Macro Local to that project: **MYDLL_EXPORTS**

```
 #ifdef  MYDLL_EXPORTS 
    /*Enabled as "export" while compiling the dll project*/
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)  
 #else
    /*Enabled as "import" in the Client side for using already created dll file*/
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)  
 #endif


  class DLLEXPORT  Class_Name { 
             //.... 
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

When compiling your library you should define a macro (command line preprocessor definition), let's call it `MY_DLL_EXPORT`.

Then in your library's code do something like this:

```
#ifdef MY_DLL_EXPORT
#  define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


class DLL_API some_class { /*...*/ }
```